# Compute class and instance hash

Tags: python, object, hash

I need to compute a "hash" which allows me to uniquely identify an object, both it's contents and the parent class.

By comparing these "hashes" i want to be able to tell if an object has changed since the last time it was scanned.

I have found plenty of examples on how to make an object hashable, however not so much about how to compute a hash of the parent class.

It is important to note comparisons are made during different executions. I say this because I think comparing the `id()` of the object since the id/address of the object might be different for different executions.

I thought of resorting to inspect but I fear it might not be very efficient, also I am not very sure how that would work if the object's parent class is inheriting from another class.

If I had access to the actual memory raw data where the instance and the class' code is stored, I could just compute the hash of that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just generate a hash of your object's `__dict__` property if you want to know if it's changed since the last check. I don't think that taking its class into account is important here.

Comment: I'm not sure what case is not covered by the built-in [`hash()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash)? Can you expand on that?

Comment: @TemporalWolf if you have `foo`, an instance of `class Foo`, and do `foo.bar = 1`, `hash(foo)` will generate a value that will remain the same after you do `foo.bar = 2`. OP wants to detect this kind of change.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Which can be used `hash(repr(obj.__dict__))`

Comment: @TemporalWolf `repr` is not reliable in this case since it won't give you the keys in a fixed order, nor will it give you ordered keys in dicts that the object might contain.

Comment: Is this not possible? Could I visit the compiled pyc files, get the section that defines a class and then work recursively through inheritance to get a complete hash of the class?

Comment: "I need to compute a "hash" which allows me to uniquely identify an object" - in general, hashes don't actually do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General idea is to serialize object and then take a hash. Then, the only question is to find a good library. Let's try **dill**:

```
>>>import dill
>>>class a():
    pass
>>>b = a()
>>>b.x = lambda x:1
>>> hash(dill.dumps(b))
2997524124252182619
>>> b.x = lambda x:2
>>> hash(dill.dumps(b))
5848593976013553511
>>> a.y = lambda x: len(x)
>>> hash(dill.dumps(b))
-906228230367168187
>>> b.z = lambda x:2
>>> hash(dill.dumps(b))
5114647630235753811
>>>
```

Looks good?

dill: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work! Now I am having some troubles importing it into scons but that is another matter ;)

Answer (score 0):

To detect if an object has changed, you could generate a hash of its JSON representation and compare to the latest hash generated by the same method.

```
import json

instance.foo = 5
hash1 = hash(json.dumps(instance.__dict__, sort_keys=True))

instance.foo = 6
hash2 = hash(json.dumps(instance.__dict__, sort_keys=True))

hash1 == hash2
>> False

instance.foo = 5
hash3 = hash(json.dumps(instance.__dict__, sort_keys=True))

hash1 == hash3
>> True
```

Or, since `json.dumps` gives us a string, you can simply compare them instead of generating a hash.

```
import json

instance.foo = 5
str1 = json.dumps(instance.__dict__, sort_keys=True)

instance.foo = 6
str2 = json.dumps(instance.__dict__, sort_keys=True)

str1 == str2
>> False
```

Comment: I have been testing and it does not seem to work... again only the objects variables seem to be taken into account... if go ahead and add a method to the class or modify some constant the hash is still the same....